# How to listen for events in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically building required components as per css

provided , this way  dynamically

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseinner.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < responseinner[i].type.length; k++) {
        random_number += 1;
        htmlbuilder.append('<div  data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + obj.name + '</h3><div class="prd-items-detials"><ul><li class="head"><form><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="' + random_number + '" data-mini="true"><label for="checkbox-mini-0">' + responseinner[i].type[k] + '</label></form></li><li class="prd-items-qt"><div class="col"><i class="minus"></i><i class="qt">1</i><i class="plus"></i></div><div class="col"></div><div id ="' + responseinner[i].type[k] + '" class="col">Rs: ' + responseinner[i].price[k] + '/-</div></li></ul></div></div>');

    }
}
```

Finally . i have registered with the click event for the above generated checkbox .

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function (e) {

      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {



      }

});
```

Is there any way i can access data present at below div

```
<div id ="' + responseinner[i].type[k] + '" class="col">Rs: ' + responseinner[i].price[k] + '/-</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PpKpa/

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Question. Search before posting a question.

Any way, Use [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) / [Children Method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) with [HTML Method](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: for me it seems very tough , as i am new to js .

Comment: thanks for the answer ,  i will search for Jquery Child selector and do this .

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `change` event, **which fires when a checkbox or radio button changes from not checked to checked**, you do not have to test for if `:checked`. You are sure if the `change` event triggered, then the element is `checked`.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("change", ".checkboxclas", function (e) {

        //if($(this).is(':checked'))
        //{ no need for this if

        //YOUR CODE HERE

        //}

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip  i needed a if else block as i need to append or remove from the div as per checkbox event .